# Define Derivative of Product of Polynomials

Tags: derivatives, polynomials, products

I have a a problem with defining a certain term...

The derivative of a product of polynomials is the sum of derivatives of the products of the summands of the polynomials of the original product. (right?)

Say we have a product $P$ of n polynomials $p_i$:

$P \equiv \prod_1^n p_i$

Then

$P' = \sum (\square)'$

where $\square$ are the products of $n$ factors of the summands of the polynomials $p_i$.

So for example:

$a \equiv a_1 + a_2$

$b \equiv b_1 + b_2$

Then

$(a \times b)' = ((a_1+a_2)\times(b_1 + b_2))' = (a_1 \times b_1)' + (a_1 \times b_2)' + (a_2 \times b_1)' + (a_2 \times b_2)'$

So, the summands in the last part are all my $\square$s. And they all have 2 factors, because my initial product has two polynomials in it.

My question now is: How do I define those squares aka "the products of $n$ factors of the summands of the polynomials $p_i$"?

I hope I could convey my question properly.

Comment: Please, edit your post.. Latex isn't visible

Comment: @sinbadh Are talking about the `\square` $\square$? It seems to be on purpose.

Comment: it is on purpose

Answer (score 2):

$P' = \sum_i ( p_i' \prod_{j \neq i} p_j )$.

Comment: well, yes, that is the generalization of the product rule ($(f\times g)' = f' \times g + f \times g'$). This is of course equivalent to my thing there, but it does not capture the individual summands in a "structural" way... in the lack of better words..., does it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are looking for then...

Comment: I think an expression, that captures all the summands of the product of n factors, which can all be different and are themselves individual sums. The n factors can be iterated over, because they are known.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking for

Answer (score 2):

Howabout

$$ P'=p_1\cdots p_n \left( \frac{p'_1}{p_1}+\cdots+\frac{p'_n}{p_n}\right) $$

For a quick derivation, let $P=p_1\cdots p_2$.

Then $$ \ln(P)=\ln(p_1 \cdots p_n)=\ln(p_1)+\cdots+\ln(p_n)$$

Differentiate both sides to get:
$$ \frac{P'}{P}=\frac{p_1'}{p_1}+\cdots+\frac{p_n'}{p_n}$$
Hence,
$$ P'=P\left( \frac{p_1'}{p_1}+\cdots+\frac{p_n'}{p_n} \right)$$
$$ = p_1\cdots p_n \left( \frac{p_1'}{p_1}+\cdots+\frac{p_n'}{p_n} \right)$$

Comment: I have tried to understand your equation, but I don't. How do you arrive at this and why does it involve dividing the derived polynomials by their un-derived forms?

Comment: Just expand the product out and you'll arrive at the expression given by the previous poster. Alternatively, you could use logarithmic differentiation to derive it (I'll add the details to that momentaarily)

Comment: Just added details